# How to crop an image in Edge & IE 11 to zoom out (negative sx/sy or swidth/sheight too large)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html5-canvas, drawing, microsoft-edge

My problem is with `ctx.drawImage(img,sx,sy,swidth,sheight,x,y,width,height);` in that **when `sx` or `sy` are negative**, both IE and Edge browsers simply don't seem to display any image at all. **If `swidth` or `sheight` are greater than `img`'s dimensions**, neither IE nor Edge will display the image either.

I have some code a lot like what's found here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage3

**This is a copy of the code from that site:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Image to use:</p>
<img id="scream" src="img_the_scream.jpg" alt="The Scream" width="220" height="277">

<p>Canvas:</p>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img, -50, -100, 600, 400, 10, 10, 150, 160); //In Chrome, this will zoom out from the image, in Edge or IE 11, the image won't even appear on screen.
};
</script>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> The canvas tag is not supported in Internet 
Explorer 8 and earlier versions.</p> //That's fine, I'm just here about IE 11 today.

</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to crop arbitrary images that may be very tall and skinny or wide and short such that they fit into a square.
Like this: [image]

**How can I crop an image in IE and Edge that will fit into a square such that I'm *adding* whitespace around it?** It seems like Microsoft only ever expects me to be zooming in on an image, not zooming out. Note: This works great in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I get the exact same results in IE, Chrome, FX and Edge. Check the values that you are using in each browser (50,0,150,200,10,10,150,160)... also check each browsers zoom settings are the same and the display DPI settings... to zoom an image in canvas you can use the transform method.

[image]

Comment: The problem I face is input specific, if sx/sy are negative or swidth/sheight are larger than the img's original dimensions, it fails. This works in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: can you update your question then with the code you are using... you do know that w3schools.com have their own support forums? Also they are not associated with the W3C.org... see w3fools.com

Comment: I've updated the code in my question to reflect the problem. All I've changed is the values of sx, sy, swidth, and sheight.